# Find the position of the element in the whole html document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't mean the position, x and y!
I want to find the position of the element based on its class. For example, in the code of the html document, we have 4 `test` classes. When one of them is clicked, I want to find the position that of elements among other friends who shared the same class.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p class="test">one</p>
    </div>
    <p class="test">two</p>
    <span href="" class="test">three</span>
</div>
<div class="test">four</div>
```

Comment: *I don't mean the position, x and y! I want to find the position of the element based on its class.* Huh??

Comment: My English is very bad, I used google translate. I just want to find the position of the element in the code based on its class name, not the position of the element in the monitor that outputs x,y.

Comment: So if we searched for the `.test` element with the text of "four", what result would you expect? 2 (it's the second, or last, child element of the `<body>`, 4 (it's the last of four elements with that specific class-name), or 6 (unlikely, but it's the last element of the `<body>` and there are five other elements in the DOM)? Do you want a numeric result, do you want a CSS selector, xpath, something else entirely?

Comment: An expected result will help to determine the intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$.index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

```js
const $els = $('.test');
$els.click(function() {
  const index = $els.index(this);
  console.log('The clicked element is the number', index);
});
```

Comment: Did you search for a dupe?